# Is there a cleaner or more efficient way to remove all values in a sorted linked list that appear in another sorted linked list?

Tags: java, sortedlist

I'm currently doing some practice problems for a course I'll be taking in the fall and I ran into this question:

> Write a method removeAll that could be added to the `LinkedIntList` class. The method should **efficiently remove from a sorted list of integers all values appearing in a second sorted list of integers**. For example, suppose `LinkedIntList` variables `list1` and `list2` refer to the following lists:
>
> `list1`: [1, 3, 5, 7]
>
> `list2`: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>
> If the call `list1.removeAll(list2)` is made, the lists should store
> the following values after the call:
>
> `list1`: [7]
>
> `list2`: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>
> Both lists are guaranteed to be in sorted (non-decreasing) order, although there might be duplicates in either list. Because the lists are sorted you can solve this problem very efficiently with a single pass through the data. Your solution is required to run in **O(M + N)** time where **M** and **N** are the lengths of the two lists.
>
> You may not call any other methods of the class to solve this problem, **you may not construct any new nodes**, and you may not use any auxiliary data structures to solve this problem (such as an array, `ArrayList`, `Queue`, `String`, etc.). You also may not change any data fields of the nodes. **You must solve this problem by rearranging the links of the lists.**

In order to solve this problem, there's a custom LinkedIntList and ListNode class that's provided.

```
public class LinkedIntList {
    private ListNode front;    // head of the list
    ...
}

public class ListNode {
    public int data;    // value stored in this node of the list
    public ListNode next;    // reference to next node in the list (null if end of list)
    ...
}
```

I solved this question in O(M + N) time in one pass. However, I'm wondering if there's any way to solve this question more efficiently. I have a nested if-else block within an if-statement and I think it could be cleaned up. I have included my code below.

```
public void removeAll(LinkedIntList list2) {
    if (this.front != null && list2.front != null) {
        // iterators for the list to remove values from
        ListNode prev = null;
        ListNode current = this.front;

        // iterator for the list where values from list1 may appear
        ListNode list2Current = list2.front;

        // reference to the front of list1
        ListNode head = current;

        while (current != null && list2Current != null) {

            while (current != null && current.data < list2Current.data) {
                prev = current;
                current = current.next;
            }

            while (current != null && list2Current != null && list2Current.data < current.data) {
                list2Current = list2Current.next;
            }

            if (current != null && list2Current != null && current.data == list2Current.data) {
                // prev can only be null if current is still pointing at the front of list1
                if (prev == null) {
                    ListNode nextup = current.next;
                    current.next = null;
                    current = nextup;
                    head = current;
                } else {
                    prev.next = current.next;
                    current = prev.next;
                }
            } else if (current != null) {
                prev = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
        }
        front = head;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't actually a response to your question, but to your assignment. LinkedLists are part of the curriculum, but nobody uses them. Personally I think it would be fun, interesting and marketable(!) to do this in JavaScript using indexedDB (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) :)

Comment: @ControlAltDel Doubly linked lists are commonly used to implement queues. Singly linked lists are usually the default list type in functional languages, and they are also used to implement stacks. Maybe the java.util.LinkedList class isn't used very often (I wouldn't know), but that's no reason not to learn about linked lists.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Good Points, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no faster than `O(M+N)` solution to this problem as all elements of both list should be iterated over.
However, the solution could be coded simpler, for example:

```
    public void removeAll(LinkedIntList list2) {
        ListNode previous = front;
        ListNode current = front;
        ListNode toRemove = list2.front;

        while (current != null && toRemove != null) {
            if (current.data < toRemove.data) {
                previous = current;
                current = current.next;
            } else if (current.data > toRemove.data) {
                toRemove = toRemove.next;
            } else {
                if (current == front) {
                    front = current.next;
                } else {
                    previous.next = current.next;
                }
                current = current.next;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. It also looks cleaner because there are no while loops within the main while loop, eliminating the need to consistently check if current or toRemove are null.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea for your solution. This problem requires that you examine each entry in the list at least once, so by definition you can't do any better than single-pass linear time. I believe you found the optimal solution.

Some notes about your code:

```
 if (prev == null) {
    ListNode nextup = current.next;
    current.next = null;
    current = nextup;
}
```

You detached the node to be deleted, but you never attach the next node (the new `current`) to the list. Your list head will still be pointing to the "deleted" node. (I think you may have tried to fix this problem with `front = head` at the end of the loop, but you never update `head`, so that doesn't really have any effect. I would just remove that line altogether.)

Here's how I would rewrite the `if`:

```
if (current != null && list2Current != null && current.data == list2Current.data) {
    if (prev == null) {
        this.first = current.next;
    } else {
        prev.next = current.next;
        prev = current;
    }
    current = current.next;
}
```

Regarding the `else if`: the *only* way both the `while` loops exited is if

1. We reached the end of this list, in which case we're done; OR
2. We reached the end of list2, in which case we're done; OR
3. The data at the current node of this list == the data at the current node of list2

So theoretically, you don't even need to check for equality. There's no situation in which you both need to continue and end up inside that `else` branch.

There are other ways to make this same solution with cleaner code (like @MartinBG's answer), but I tried to clean up your code specifically.